# How to update content in a block after flagging event without page reload?

Tags: drupal-8

Hy, I'm fairly new to Drupal 8. I have a custom entity type called Event and using the Flag module I added the option to "Favorite the event" and finally I have a custom block which displays the number of Events each User has favorited. Everytime a user "favorites" a new event the block obviously shows the old value. I have set up cache invalidation, so if the user refreshes the page he will see the updated/correct number. Now my question is, how can I update the block's number without refreshing the page. I can't find an easy example anywhere. The Flag module's docs are outdated or incomplete and I think the answer lies in subscribing to the Flagging event and performing actions there, I just don't know how to include or perform a javascript action ("if it's needed, I assume it is). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax Command on block and don't forget to attach ajax.core library to block.